# How to add an UITextField to SCNNode geometry material in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, scenekit, scnnode

I'm trying to make an UITextField as a SCNNode geometry material. This code works well:

```
func createBox(transform: SCNMatrix4) {
    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, length: 0.5, chamferRadius: 1)

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 50))
    textField.text = "Hello"

    let sides = [
        textField,       // Front
        UIColor.black,   // Right
        UIColor.black,   // Back
        UIColor.black,   // Left
        UIColor.black,   // Top
        UIColor.black    // Bottom
    ]

    let materials = sides.map { (side) -> SCNMaterial in
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = side
    material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true
    return material
  }

  box.materials = materials

  let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
  boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
  boxNode.transform = transform

  sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
}
```

But when I tap on the text field the keyboard doesn't appear. Why is it happening? Is there ways to fix it? I need the user can enter some text in the field. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn’t appear because you don’t actually tap the textfield element but a graphical representation of it. Possibly you can get this to work by getting the texture coordinates of a hittest in a tap gesture event, and mapping those to the view of the textfield, and then send a TouchUpInside event to the textfield, and then update the texture.

Comment: You may want to add the tap gesture .. like below         let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTap(withGestureRecognizer:)))
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer) and handle  the tap some thing like belo